# RecyclerView item animate strangely in fragment shared element animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, fragment

I studied Android Fragment shared element animation.
I think almost every work is done for fragment shared element animation.
However the result is so strange.
I expected that the touched item in recyclerview will animate to the main center image in DetailFragment. Animations was started but the starting position is wrong.
What is wrong with this project?

The result animation is here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbxJ5.gif

The MainActivity is like this

```
class BodyCheckDemoActivity : AppCompatActivity() , SimpleNavigate{
    lateinit var binding: ActivityBodyCheckDemoBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityBodyCheckDemoBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_body_check_demo);
    }

    override fun navigate( fragment : Class<*>, shareElement : List<View>?) {
        val fragment : Fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            fragment.classLoader!!,
            fragment.name
        )

        val beginTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        beginTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        beginTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment )
        shareElement?.forEach{ v-> beginTransaction.addSharedElement(v, v.transitionName)}
        beginTransaction.commit()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    private val map = HashMap<String,Any>();
    override fun getBundle(): MutableMap<String, Any> = map
}

fun Fragment.onBackPressed() = (activity as? SimpleNavigate)?.onBackPressed()
fun Fragment.navigate( fragment : Class<*> , shareElement : List<View>? = null ) = (activity as? SimpleNavigate)?.navigate(fragment,shareElement)
fun Fragment.getShareMap() = (activity as? SimpleNavigate)?.getBundle()
fun Fragment.getTransitionView( transitionName : String , root : View? = this.view ) : View? {
    return root?.let {
        if( it.transitionName == transitionName) it
        else (it as? ViewGroup)
            ?.children?.map{ child-> getTransitionView(transitionName, child) }?.find { childView-> childView != null }
    }
}

interface SimpleNavigate{
    fun onBackPressed()
    fun getBundle() : MutableMap<String,Any>
    fun navigate( fragment : Class<*>, shareElement : List<View>?)
}
```

and The First Fragment is like this

```
class BodyCheckMainFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = BodyCheckMainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var binding: BodyCheckMainFragmentBinding
    val viewModel: BodyCheckMainViewModel by viewModels<BodyCheckMainViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initSubscription()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.e( "MotionLayout", "onCreateView")
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<BodyCheckMainFragmentBinding>(inflater,R.layout.body_check_main_fragment, container, false)
        with(binding.recyclerview){
            adapter = MyAdapter(viewModel);
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
            setHasFixedSize(true)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        binding.vm = viewModel

    }

    private fun initSubscription() {
        viewModel.toastMsg.observe( this, Observer {
        })
        viewModel.toDetail.observe( this, Observer {
            getShareMap()!!["resourceId"] = it;
            val list = getTransitionView( it.toString() )?.let {  arrayListOf( it ) }
            getTransitionView( "bg$it" )?.let{ list?.add(it)}
            navigate( BodyCheckDetailFragment::class.java , list )
        })
    }

    class BodyCheckMainViewModel : ViewModel() {
        private val _toast = MutableLiveData<String>();
        private val _detailIndex = MutableLiveData<Int>();
        val toastMsg : LiveData<String> = _toast
        val toDetail : LiveData<Int> = _detailIndex

        fun onSymptopmpsClick( resourceId : Int){
            _detailIndex.value = resourceId;
        }

        fun onRequirementClick( index : Int){
            when(index){
                0->{ _toast.value = "Mask" }
                1->{ _toast.value = "Gloves" }
                2->{ _toast.value = "Alcohol" }
                3->{ _toast.value = "Soap" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with related xml views

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".bodycheck.BodyCheckDemoActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    ...
    some views

    ...

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_symp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and Adapter

```
class BodyState(
    val title : String,
    val resourceId: Int
)

class BodyStateHolder(
    val view: WidgetBodycheckSymptompsBinding,
    val itemClick : (BodyState) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root){
    lateinit var item : BodyState;
    fun binding( item : BodyState ){
        this.item = item
        view.imgSrc = item.resourceId
        view.title = item.title
        view.bg.transitionName = "bg${item.resourceId}"
        view.image.transitionName = "${item.resourceId}"
        view.root.setOnClickListener { itemClick(item) }
    }
}

class MyAdapter(val viewModel: BodyCheckMainFragment.BodyCheckMainViewModel) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BodyStateHolder>() {
    val itemList = arrayListOf(
        BodyState( "Fever" , R.drawable.img_face_fever ),
        BodyState( "Cough" , R.drawable.img_face_cough ),
        BodyState( "Sore troath" , R.drawable.img_face_sore_troath ),
        BodyState( "Tiredness" , R.drawable.img_face_headache ),
        BodyState( "Aches" , R.drawable.img_face_sore_troath_middle ),
        BodyState( "Shortness breath" , R.drawable.img_face_comportable )
    )
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BodyStateHolder {
        return BodyStateHolder(
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.widget_bodycheck_symptomps, parent, false )
        ) {
            viewModel.onSymptopmpsClick( it.resourceId )
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = itemList.size;
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BodyStateHolder, position: Int) = holder.binding(itemList[position]);
}
```

The second framgent is here

```
class BodyCheckDetailFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        postponeEnterTransition()
        sharedElementEnterTransition = AutoTransition()
        sharedElementReturnTransition = AutoTransition()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<BodyCheckDetailFragmentBinding>(inflater, R.layout.body_check_detail_fragment, container, false)
        binding.srcImg = getShareMap()!!["resourceId"] as Int
        binding.faceImage.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object:ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener{
            override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                startPostponedEnterTransition()
                binding.faceImage.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                return true;
            }
        })
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

with only related view xml

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="srcImg"
        type="int" />
</data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bodyCheckPrimaryColor"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/body_check_detail_fragment_scene">

    ... some views...
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/face_image"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:transitionName="@{`bg`+srcImg}">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/img_face_fever"
            android:srcGlide="@{srcImg}"
            android:transitionName="@{srcImg+``}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Comment: Share your codes in which you implemented shared element transition logic. Item click, navigation, destination and layout xml resource

Comment: @RustamSamandarov thanks your feedback. I edited my question. Please check.